# Ant BND task does not produce bundle containing any items

Tags: ant, osgi

I'm having trouble producing a bundle after converting a maven project to an ant project.  The bnd ant task creates test.jar but the file only includes a META-INF.  The eclipse project is named testproj.  What am I missing?  Also, does anyone know of a place with more bnd ant task examples?  The bnd site itself is a little lacking in this regard, especially with how to build the classpath values.

```
<project name="testproj" basedir="." default="build">

<patternset id="project.deploy.jars">
    <include name="slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar" />
    <include name="logback-core-0.9.28.jar" />
    <include name="logback-classic-0.9.28.jar" />
    <include name="org.osgi.compendium-4.2.0.jar" />
    <include name="org.apache.felix.http.jetty-2.2.0.jar" />
    <include name="jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar" />
    <include name="mail-1.4.4-1.0.0.jar" />
    <include name="commons-io-2.0.1.jar" />
    <include name="commons-lang-2.6.jar" />
    <include name="commons-codec-1.5.jar" />
    <include name="commons-httpclient-3.1-osgi-1.0.0.jar" />
    <include name="bndlib-1.43.0.jar" />
    <include name="ojdbc5-osgi-1.0.0.jar" />
    <include name="joda-time-1.6.2.jar" />
    <include name="cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution-1.2.jar" />
</patternset>

<path id="bnd.classpath">
    <fileset dir="setup/external">
        <patternset refid="project.deploy.jars" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="build" description="Build the bundle">

    <taskdef resource="aQute/bnd/ant/taskdef.properties"
        classpath="setup/dev/biz.aQute.bnd.jar"
        />

    <pathconvert property="bnd.classpath.string" pathsep=",">
        <path refid="bnd.classpath" />
        <mapper>
            <chainedmapper>
              <flattenmapper/>
              <regexpmapper from="(.*)" to="setup/external/\1" casesensitive="no"/>
            </chainedmapper>
        </mapper>
    </pathconvert>

    <echo>${bnd.classpath.string}</echo>

    <bnd 
      classpath="target/classes,${bnd.classpath.string}"
      eclipse="true" 
      failok="false" 
      exceptions="true" 
      output="test.jar"
      files="test.bnd"/>

</target>

</project>

test.bnd:
Import-Package:com.test.service, oracle.sql, oracle.jdbc, oracle.jdbc.driver, *
Export-Package:com.test.service
Service-Component:com.test.*
```

Comment: BNDtools provides more high level tooling ontop of BND, might be worth a look at least wrt to examples:  http://bndtools.org/

Comment: Yeah I do like bndtools, but my manager is pushing for an ant-offline build process only.  Thanks though.

Comment: Is it possible that the package `com.test.service` cannot be found in the classpath, i.e. in the `target.classes` directory? If that package does not exist on the classpath then your bundle will be empty (aside from the manifest). BTW your manager should know that you can use Bndtools AND have an offline build process ;-)

Comment: I've updated the item with the full build file just in case its something obvious I've missed.  I must've done something right because today I get the service interface showing up, but the impl class doesn't make it into the bundle, and neither does a service component xml.  I'm sending the .zip to Peter (minus jars) so he can take a look at it.  Thanks Neil!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following help from the group at Google Groups bndtools (which is a group for for both bndtools and bnd), the issue is apparently that the .bnd file does not contain the Private-Package header.  This is used to specify the implementation package so make it a base package for all the classes you want brought in.

After I added it, all the classes showed up and the component xml appeared again.

Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

1) Did you look at the ant support included in bndtools? Neil and I go out of our way to make bndtools run in offline mode. 
2) The build.xml looks not proper ant syntax? Can you make a small example and post the proper files?
3) bnd should never generate a jar without a MANIFEST.MF file. Does the run have an error?

If you can't solve the problem feel free to send me a zip file with the setup and I'll check what's going on (and report here).